# Laravel mail notification template includes extraneous line breaks (<br>)

Tags: laravel, email, templates, notifications, line-breaks

I'm having a strange issue where a standard Laravel notification mail is being filled with extraneous line breaks. It looks like all the line breaks from the html files are converted to `<br>`s.

Here's an example:

[image: notification]

I'm using Laravel 5.7, and it's not a clean install, so it might totally be something related to it. It's a pretty basic app though, with little or no customization. I have always followed the upgrade guides and git commits to keep it updated with the latest changes.

Does anybody have any clue of how to fix this?

Edit:
for comparison, here's a portion of the original source:

```
<tr>
    <td class="header">
        <a href="{{ $url }}">
            {{ $slot }}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here's the resulting code after Laravel does its things (I've removed the inlined css for readability):

```
<tr>
<br><td class="header" style="...">
<br><a href="http://localhost:8888" style="..."><br>
            Laravel<br></a><br>
</td>
<br>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post your code for the notification in order for us to help out further.

Comment: It's just the basic reset password notification from Laravel, no changes. What part of code would you look at?

Answer (score 1):

Check `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` you might find something similar to this: `Blade::setEchoFormat('nl2br(e(%s, true))');`

This will turn your new lines into `<br>` tags. See [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was not Laravel, rather it was from my email provider. They automatically convert newline characters in the sent mail to the `<br>` tag. I used the code below to remove every newline character from my email before sending and it solved the problem.

```
$html = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($html));
```